# Unconfirmed transaction in memory pool

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, getmemorypool

In February 2021, I sent some bitcoin from bitcoin core account. I choose a low transaction fee. The transaction is down as 'unconfirmed, memory pool'. The bitcoin has not appeared at the receiving address, and the transaction does not show up on tradeblock or on blockchain explorer. Can anyone advise on this? How do I get my bc back?